# Como fazer para que fase ande junto com personagem no JFrame Java?

Tags: java, jogos

Eu queria saber se como fazer uma câmera para personagem quando ele chegar no fim do painel começar ir junto ao personagem, pois ao definir um tamanho `this.setSize(500,500);` o personagem ao passar essa marcar ele some e se você limitar a movimentação ele fica preso nesse quadrado.

Comment: Olá. Por favor, forneça mais detalhes. O que é o "fim do painel"? Vc está usando um `panel` pra simular uma rolagem horizontal, é isso? Edite a pergunta pra fornecer mais informações pra que alguém possa te ajudar, como, por exemplo, adicionando imagens da tela que tem e que deseja e o trecho de código relevante.

Answer (score 0):

Como você tem um JPanel grande, é possível que você já tenha adicionado ele a um JScrollPane, para que possa "ver" o JPanel inteiro, de acordo com a barra, caso não tenha feito isso, dê uma pesquisada em JScrollPanes, mas basicamente você vai fazer o seguinte:

```
Container cp=getContentPane();
JPanel pnJogo=new JPanel();//aqui vai ficar a interface do jogo
JScrollPane sc=new JScrollPane(pnJogo);//adicionando o painel ao ScrollPane
```

Após feito isso, você pode setar o valor do seu Scroll conforme vai adicionando, mas a partir desse ponto, o critério do setValue é contigo!

```
final JScrollBar bar1 = seuScroll.getHorizontalScrollBar();
bar1.setValue(10);//isso pode estar dentro de um for, ou um ActionListener também, por exemplo.
```

E, seria uma boa ideia também, você bloquear o ScrollPane, para que o usuário não possa "analisar" a fase antes de ir para frente, pois assim, tiraria a "emoção" do jogo, peço desculpas, mas essa é uma ideia, não sei como "bloquear" a barra (se alguém souber, fique a vontade para editar a resposta)

um exemplo de como você pode fazer isso, aí confome o personagem for andando, você vai aumentando o valor do scrollBar

Comment: Creio que isso não vá resolver já que jpanel não possui scrollbar por si só.

Comment: pelo que eu entendi, o JPanel onde é o jogo, é um JPanel grande, por isso não está sendo possível "coloca-lo na tela", então a solução seria adicionar esse JPanel em um JScrollPane e só então adicionar o JScrollPane no Container dele, caso tenha feito isso, a vida dele irá facilitar, pois a maneira de mostrar a fase, ele já tem, basta bloquear a edição do mesmo, para ele não ver "a frente" da fase e, a partir disso ir setando conforme o personagem avança

Comment: Sim, mas isso não foi explicado na resposta. Da forma como está, não vai ajudar muito, talvez editando e fornecendo esse detalhes que você acabou de comentar, a resposta fique mais completa e util ao OP.

Comment: Tudo bem então, vou fazer isso :)